# How to determine the effective class (Bean) to be used when using an interface as a class member using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, interface, conditional-on-property

Is it possible to achieve the following?

I want to determine the type of a class to be used at runtime with Spring Boot. Hence, I defined an interface `MyInterface` defining the required methods:

```
public interface MyInterface<C extends DocumentContext> {
    MyResult<C> doForX(C documentContext);
    MyResult<C> doForY(C documentContext);
}
```

An abstract base class implements this interface and provide some common methods:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public abstract class BaseClass<C extends DocumentContext> implements MyInterface<C> {
    private MyInterface myInterface;
    
    ...
    
    public MyResult<C> doForX(C documentContext) { ... }
    public Myresult<C> doForY(C documentContext) { ... }
}
```

This base class is the parent for two subclasses:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "sanitizerType", havingValue = "REGEX", matchIfMissing = false)
public class FirstClass<C extends documentContext> extends BaseClass<C> implements<MyInterface<C> {
    ...override base methods
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "sanitizerType", havingValue = "SAX", matchIfMissing = false)
public class SecondClass<C extends documentContext> extends BaseClass<C> implements<MyInterface<C> {
    ...override base methods
}
```

A class using one of the two concrete subclasses:

```
public class MyUsingClass extends AnotherClass {
    public MyUsingclass(MyInterface<ADocumentContext> myInterfaceImpl, ...)
    
    ...
}
```

This compiles but when I try to run the application I get:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 1 of constructor in MyUsingClass required a bean of type
> 'MyInterface' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'MyInterface' in your configuration.

In my application.properties I have:

```
# ... [SAX | REGEX]
#sanitizerType=REGEX
```

...and I have a Properties class:

```
@Value("${sanitizerType:REGEX}")
private SanitizerType sanitizerType;
```

, whereby SanitizerType is just:

```
public enum SanitizerType {
    REGEX, SAX
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you would like to "*determine the type of a class to be used at runtime with Spring Boot*".
I'm not sure if you want your ***"class to be used"*** change while your application is running depending on current condidionts or set once when the application boots and use it always until the app is running.

If you uncomment this line of your application.properties **#sanitizerType=REGEX**
Your code should work - but it simply defines the SanitizerType (hence your **MyInterface** implementation) once when you start your application.

Please note that by setting a private field of Properties class you don't set the property globally (at least not the way you showed in the question), but only set the private field value either according what's set in your properties file or (if value is missing in properties) to "REGEX".
If you want to use it in different places of your program you need to inject it differently